# How to find the largest network cluster?

Tags: netlogo

"nw:weak-component-clusters" in the Networks extension will return a list of weakly connected agentsets. I would like to output the number of turtles in the biggest of these.

So

```
show nw:weak-component-clusters
observer: [(agentset, 15 turtles) (agentset, 20 turtles) (agentset, 16 turtles)]
```

would return 20.

Is there an easy way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but it will work:

```
to find_max
let my_list []
let my_max 0
let turt_list nw:weak-component-clusters
foreach turt_list [x -> ask x [set my_list lput count x my_list]]
set my_max max my_list
show my_max
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler approach using `map`:

```
to-report count-of-largest-cluster
  report max (map count nw:weak-component-clusters)
end
```

[`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) takes a reporter and a list as inputs, and reports a list whose items are the result of the input reporter being run for every item of the input list.

`nw:weak-component-clusters` is a list of agentsets, therefore `map count nw:weak-component-clusters` is a list of each agentset's count. Note that the parentheses in my solution are optional and only there for readability.